# Angular Material Menu not openning directly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material 5, i have 2 menus, When I open one menu, it works as expected, but when i try to open another menu, i have to click twice

The first click hides the first menu, and the second click opens the desired menu.

here's my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-menu-8nrvrj?file=app%2Fmenu-icons-example.html

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <!-- First menu -->
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <!-- pass local reference of mat-menu to be opened on this click -->
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <!-- give local reference and tell this is manu by assigning 'matMenu' -->
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
        <span>Redial</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item disabled>
        <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
        <span>Check voicemail</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
        <span>Disable alerts</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <!-- Second menu -->

    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2">
      <!-- pass local reference of mat-menu to be opened on this click -->
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu">
      <!-- give local reference and tell this is manu by assigning 'matMenu' -->
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
        <span>Redial</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item disabled>
        <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
        <span>Check voicemail</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
        <span>Disable alerts</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>

  <!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
  can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
</div>
```

How can i open directly my meny without have to click twice

Comment: For me when i try to click 2nd menu top right corner it opening in single click only. So think that's correct. ?

Comment: open the menu on left and let it open and try to open the one on right while the left one  is still opening, @Ｒの卄ＩＴ

Comment: That's because it has a backdrop to support closing it when clicking outside. If your version is higher than in the Stackblitz example you provided, you could specifiy  `[hasBackdrop]="false"` on `<mat-menu>`, but I'm unsure if you want that behaviour.

Comment: thanks @Silvermind that was close to what i'm locking for, it works but my first menu now is no longer dispearing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make another click and not to affect first one, you have to manipulate the overlay and out of menu area. ***Buttons are under overlay*** so first click cause the first menu close. That's why you should increase your buttons layer over the overlay. Start with css ;

**CSS**:

```
.upperButton {
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

and add this class to your buttons. But this manipulation cause click options disable. You should call click function manually so add click functions with button indexes.

**HTML**:

```
<button
      mat-icon-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
      class="upperButton"
      (click)="clickMenu(0)"
    >
...
<button
      mat-icon-button
      [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2"
      class="upperButton"
      (click)="clickMenu(1)"
    >
```

Configure your function to open or close button elements on ts file and don't forget to import,

**TS**:

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';

/**
 * @title Menu with icons
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'menu-icons-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-icons-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['menu-icons-example.css'],
})
export class MenuIconsExample {
  @ViewChildren(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>;

  constructor() {}

  clickMenu(index: number) {
    this.trigger.toArray().forEach((item: MatMenuTrigger, i: number) => {
      if (i !== index && item.menuOpen) {
        item.closeMenu();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

It will work for now on but buttons and menu-items will be overlapped. You can solve this problem with two ways. First one that I will explain is drop the top position of menu-item area. As to second one is changing display of buttons. Let's look at my way:

Add customized position of menu-items to **CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .positionMenu {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Then add `positionMenu` class to `<mat-menu>` in **HTML**;

```
...
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="positionMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
        <span>Redial</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item disabled>
        <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
        <span>Check voicemail</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
        <span>Disable alerts</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
...
```

Tested and worked well. This is the way for customization.